# Keep rows based on multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
DateX     DateY     DateZ
X_value   Y_value   Z_Value
```

I want to keep only the rows where I have a value for both X, Y, and Z on the same date. How do I do this in R?

Comment: please use `dput()` to provide a sample of your data. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidelines on how to create reproducible examples.

Answer (score -1):

You should give us a data example, but if your dataframe is named `dat`, maybe the following will do.

```
inx <- dat$DateX == dat$DateY & dat$DateY == dat$DateZ
inx <- inx & !is.na(dat$DateX) & !is.na(dat$DateY) & !is.na(dat$DateZ)
result <- dat[inx, ]
```

Comment: How do I give a data example?

Comment: @Rui I think this fails, as it misses out the part to check whether all three variables have values or not.

Comment: @Aramis7d Do you mean, it should remove `NA` values? Try it after my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Without looking at the data, you may want to check something like the `complete.cases` functions:

```
df %>%
 filter((DateX == DateY) & (DateX == DateZ)) %>%
 filter(complete.cases(.))
```